# Display nested weather data from a German API (DWD). Numbers in headers a problem?

Tags: reactjs, json, api, nested, display

I have worked with openweathermap before and displaying weather data has worked very well.

I've now tried to use the same code to fetch weather data from a German API (Deutscher Wetterdienst "DWD").
But the JSON structure is a little different so I cannot display the data with my code.
I don't understand the error text displayed in the terminal. It says "Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}".

First of all here is a the JSON structure from the API:

```
{
  "10384": {
    "forecast1": {
      "stationId": "10384",
      "start": 1664834400000,
      "timeStep": 3600000,
      "temperature": [],
      "temperatureStd": [],
      "windSpeed": null,
      "windDirection": null,
      "windGust": null,
      "icon": [  
      ],
      "precipitationTotal": [],
      "precipitationProbablity": null,
      "precipitationProbablityIndex": null
    },
    "forecastStart": null,
    "days": [
      {
        "stationId": null,
        "dayDate": "2022-10-04",
        "temperatureMin": 93,
        "temperatureMax": 157,
        "icon": 3,
        "icon1": null,
        "icon2": null,
        "precipitation": 0,
        "windSpeed": 111,
        "windGust": 296,
        "windDirection": 2740,
        "sunshine": 1920
      }
     ],
}
```

The number "10384" at the top is the ID of the weather station.
After fetching the API, I store the json object into a state variable called "data".

Then I want to display "10384"-> "forecast1"  -> "temperature"
and
"10384" -> "days" -> "temperatureMin".

But I can't because of the "10384" being an integer.

My full code:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      const getData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await 
     fetch('https://dwd.api.proxy.bund.dev/v30/stationOverviewExtended?stationIds=433,10384'
            ,{
              method: "GET",
              mode: "cors",
              headers: {"content-type": "application/json" }
            }
           
          )
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(
              `HTTP error. Status: ${response.status}`
            );
          }
          let actualData = await response.json();
          setData(actualData);
          console.log(actualData);
          setError(null);

        } catch(err) {
          setError(err.message);
          setData(null);
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
      getData()
    }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {error && (
        <div>{`Fehler beim Fetchen von Daten. Error fetching data - ${error}`}</div>
      )}
        <div className="widget-container">

            {/* Temepraturausgabe + Wetter-Icon*/}
            <div className="temp-container">
              <span className="tempNow">{data.10384? <h1>{data.10384.days}: null}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Somehow I cannot map over the "10384" so I can't access the nested data.

[Error I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Quf.png)

The weather station ID right at the beginning is the problem. Are numbers not allowed? how can I access the nested data?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your span as below:

```
<span className="tempNow">
  {(data && data["10384"]) ? <h1>data["10384"]?.days[0]?.temperatureMin </h1> : null}
</span>;
```

as the object keys are always strings you can access by notation `[]` ..

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I can't upvote you yet, need 15 rep. :) One more question: Since the first 'data["10384"] ?' is true, is it still neccessary for a second questionmark operator? Because it is alreay true. (<h1>data["10384"]?<---- this question mark needed? )

Comment: sure np, Not required if it is `true` .. just in case "checking" is good  "if in doubt"

Comment: Now I'm getting the error: FetchApi.js:54 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '10384'). Does it mean the fetching of the data failed? Or how is the '10384' empty?

Comment: yeah seems like `data` is null ... you can always check as `data && rest ...`  edited the answer